# Stop WebStorm From Suggesting Index Imports

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I have a shared ts library that I use for other projects. Within this library are resources that are used by other resources with the same library. This library is structured into directories like `components/*`, `interfaces/*`, `services/*`, etc. At the root of each of these directories is an `index.ts` file that re-exports the resources within that directory. This is so the consuming project can import resources like:

```
import { FooService, BarService } from 'mylib/services';
```

Instead of:

```
import { FooService } from 'mylib/services/foo-service';
import { BarService } from 'mylib/services/bar-service';
```

The annoyance is that if I use an `index.ts` file like this, WebStorm will suggest I import all library-local resources with it. I absolutely do not want to do that because it has led to unintended circular dependencies in the past. Within the lib itself, if `components/foo-component.ts` wants to import `FooService`, it should always import from `../services/foo-service.ts` and not `../services`.

But I can't get WebStorm to ignore these index files without marking them as Plain Text. Even if I exclude files named `index.ts` in `Preferences > Directories`, they will still appear as an option to include from.

[image: importing from index]

How can I tell WebStorm to ignore `index.ts` files when searching for imports? And to stop bugging me that my imports can be shortened.

Comment: Usually when you follow the arrow of the recommendation it can take you directly to the setting that controls the warning and you can turn it off there (however it may also turn off things you want)

Comment: @apokryfos That works for the annoying recommendation, but there is the second problem where automatic imports will always use the shortened version. Making automatic imports a manual process to fix every time

Answer (score -1):

In **Settings | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript | Imports**, try disabling **Use directory import when index.js is available (Node-style module resolution**

Comment: That setting isn't correct, it just changes the import to `directory/index` instead of `directory`.